# Gmail on Appengine : NoSuchMethodError: javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.combineSegments

Tags: google-app-engine, smtp, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I am accessing Gmail Imap on Appengine using XOAUTH2. Connecting to imap and searching for a message works just fine but when I try to access the message contents of `GmailMessage`, I run into

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.combineSegments()V
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.parseParameters(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:404)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:224)
```

When using mail on AppEngine with the MailService, you must not add the javax.mail.jar to the classpath, but when accessing IMAP and SMTP over the sockets API, you need to have javax.mail.jar and gimaps.jar in the classpath.

I suspect there is a conflict between the repackaged javax.mail.* classes in the AppEngine SDK and the standard java.mail.jar.
Finally, to workaround this problem, I copied the source of ParameterList and put it into a self-created 'javax.mail.internet' package and that solved this issue partially.

**I am looking for advice on the conflicting javax.mail classes**

Comment: At the end of the day, I added all the sources of javax.mail to my project and compiled them with my application. Since classes have priority over jars in class loading. It works but it is not a clean or stable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google support :

Engineering is aware of this and is evaluating an upgrade path but that hasn't been determined yet. If the workaround you've got now by uploading the 1.5 javamail is working, then I'll close this case out.